# C++ linked lists with smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I want to know about smart pointers in C++11, so I started to write my own linked list implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct link
{
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<link> next;

    link(T value) : data(value) {}
    void add_to_end(T value)
    {
        if (next)
            next->add_to_end(value);
        else
            next.reset(new link(value));
    }

};

template<typename T>
class linked_list
{
public:
    linked_list() : head(nullptr) {};
    ~linked_list() {};

    void push(T elem);
    void show(void);
    void reverse(void);
private:
    std::shared_ptr<link<T>> head;
};

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::push(T elem)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
        head.reset(new link<T>(elem));
    else
        head->add_to_end(elem);
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::reverse(void)
{
    std::shared_ptr<link<T>> prev;
    std::shared_ptr<link<T>> next;

    if (head == nullptr) return;

    while (head->next)
    {
        next = head->next;
        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next;
    }
    head->next = prev;
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::show(void)
{
    std::shared_ptr<link<T>> current(head);
    while (current)
    {
        std::cout << current->data << std::endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    linked_list<int> list;

    list.push(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(3);

    list.show();
    list.reverse();
    list.show();

    return 0;
}
```

1. I don't like to use shared pointers because they are used when multiple ownership is possible. But in linked list every node owns only the next one node. So I want to use `unique_ptr`. How can I use them? Unique pointers don't allow assignment which I use in my code.
2. I perform adding element into the end of list using `link::add_to_end` call. It looks not very good. How can I improve this code? What changes should I do if I want to write my `push_front` method to add into the head?
3. How else can I improve my code? What other problems does it have?

Comment: Why 11 and not 14?

Comment: @Babra Cunningham, I only started C++11. What are main differences between C++11 and C++14? I heard C++14 is only not very big update for c++11.

Comment: About you request #2, you should be aware that changing _what_ your code does is out of scope for this site. Work onto something that perform what you’re after, show us, and we’ll help improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get a warning from `g++ -Weffc++`:

```
144018.cpp: In instantiation of ‘link<T>::link(T) [with T = int]’:
144018.cpp:39:20:   required from ‘void linked_list<T>::push(T) [with T = int]’
144018.cpp:78:16:   required from here
144018.cpp:10:5: warning: ‘link<int>::next’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
     link(T value) : data(value) {}
     ^~~~
```

It's worth building with all the warnings you can stand.  This one is easily fixed by declaring it as

```
std::shared_ptr<link> next = {};
```

---

I found it easier to experiment with your code by encapsulating the specific pointer type within the classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct link
{
    using pointer = std::shared_ptr<link>;

    T data;
    pointer next = {};
};

template<typename T>
class linked_list
{
    using link_pointer = typename link<T>::pointer;

private:
    link_pointer head = {};
};
```

Then you can use `pointer` or `link_pointer` anywhere that `auto` won't do.

---

If I change `link::pointer` to be a `std::unique_ptr`, the errors I get are all within `reverse()` and `show()` (both of which I would implement outside of the class - the first as a specialization of `std::reverse`).  But I'm guessing you implemented them as members for the educational value, so I'll continue.  For show, you want to traverse the pointers *without transferring ownership*, so you can't use unique pointers for your traversal.  But you know you can safely use raw pointers as long as you don't let them leak outside the objects' lifetimes:

```
template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::show()
{
    auto current = head.get();
    while (current)
    {
        std::cout << current->data << std::endl;
        current = current->next.get();
    }
}
```

Your `reverse()` method *does* want to take ownership, and can use `std::move()` to do so:

```
template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::reverse()
{
    if (!head) return;

    link_pointer prev;
    link_pointer next;

    while (head->next)
    {
        next = std::move(head->next);
        head->next = std::move(prev);
        prev = std::move(head);
        head = std::move(next);
    }
    head->next = std::move(prev);
}
```

---

To add elements in O(1) time rather than O(n) time, maintain a (non-owning) pointer to the tail of the list:

```
template<typename T>
class linked_list
{
    using link_pointer = typename link<T>::pointer;

private:
    link_pointer head = {};
    link<T> *tail = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::push(T elem)
{
    auto new_link = new link<T>(std::move(elem));

    if (tail)
        tail->next.reset(new_link);
    else
        head.reset(new_link);
    tail = new_link;
}
```

---

Minor style points:

- You can write empty argument lists as `()` rather than C-style `(void)`.
- The `show()` method can be const.
- It's a bit more idiomatic to allow (raw or smart) pointer types to convert to `bool` than to test against `nullptr`:

  ```
  {
      if (head)
          head->add_to_end(elem);
      else
          head.reset(new link<T>(elem));
  }
  ```
- Constructors that immediately store their arguments can move from the argument:

  ```
  link(T value) : data{std::move(value)} {}
  ```

  This reduces copying (which may become more important when `T` is bigger than the `int` used in the test program).

---

Putting it all together, I get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct link
{
    using pointer = std::unique_ptr<link>;

    T data;
    pointer next = {};

    link(T value) : data{std::move(value)} {}
};

template<typename T>
class linked_list
{
    using link_pointer = typename link<T>::pointer;

public:
    linked_list() = default;
    ~linked_list() = default;

    void push(T elem);
    void show() const;
    void reverse();
private:
    link_pointer head = {};
    link<T> *tail = nullptr;
};

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::push(T elem)
{
    auto new_link = new link<T>(std::move(elem));

    if (tail)
        tail->next.reset(new_link);
    else
        head.reset(new_link);
    tail = new_link;
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::reverse()
{
    if (!head) return;

    link_pointer prev;
    link_pointer next;

    while (head->next)
    {
        next = std::move(head->next);
        head->next = std::move(prev);
        prev = std::move(head);
        head = std::move(next);
    }
    head->next = std::move(prev);
}

template<typename T>
void linked_list<T>::show() const
{
    auto current = head.get();
    while (current)
    {
        std::cout << current->data << std::endl;
        current = current->next.get();
    }
}


int main()
{
    linked_list<int> list;

    list.push(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(3);

    list.show();
    list.reverse();
    list.show();
}
```

---

For your next steps, I think you'll want to add an iterator type and suitable `begin()` and `end()`.  Then you'll be able to remove `show()` and replace it with a simple `for (const auto& e: list) std::cout << e;`

P.S. Thank you for providing the test program with the code - that certainly makes trying out changes easier!